# Objective-C Casting to Custom Class in conditional statement

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two classes of UICollectionViewCell - ComicStripViewCellA & ComicStripViewCellB.

Instead of

```
if (condition) {

     ComicStripViewCellA *comicStripViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"comicStripCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     comicStripViewCell.imageView.image = image;

     // Common Code Section
     comicStripViewCell.pageNumber.text = @"Something ...";
     .
     .

} else {

     ComicStripViewCellB *comicStripViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifer:@"comicStripCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     comicStripViewCell.title.text = @"Something ...";

     // Common Code Section
     comicStripViewCell.pageNumber.text = @"Something ...";
     .
     .
}
```

I want to optimize the code since a lot of the code in "Common Code Section" is the same. This is what I want to achieve:

```
Class myClass;

if (condition) {
     myClass = NSClassFromString(@"ComicStripViewCellA");
} else {
     myClass = NSClassFromString(@"ComicStripViewCellB");
}

myClass *comicStripViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifer:@"comicStripCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
comicStripViewCell.title.text = @"Something ...";

// Common Code Section
comicStripViewCell.pageNumber.text = @"Something ...";
.
.
```

I know the above code will not compile.  This is just to illustrate what I want to achieve.  Is there any way of getting the comicStripViewCell casted to a class dynamically?

Thanks in advance!

---

Thank you all for your suggestions!  I have used the @protocol and everything worked fine.

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama And then how would he proceed with properties? `<value of type id>.PROPERTY` does not compile.

Comment: on thing that may be a problem here, is that between returning a cell and dequeueing it, the class wont change, you need to use the reuse identifier to specify which one you are using and you will dequeue the correct one.

Comment: All in all, a `@protocol` is of great use in this situation (see my answer).

Comment: They should either both inherit from a common class that has the common methods/properties, or they should both conform to a protocol with the shared functionality.

Comment: no classes cannot be 'switched' by just saying it is an object of that class now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a protocol in which you declare the necessary properties and methods both classes should implement, then you'll be able to refactor your common code section.

```
@protocol Foo <NSObject>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *identifier;

@end

- (void)bar
{
    id <Foo> var = [someObject callMethod];
    var.identifier = @"quirk";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make both cells subclasses of a common parent which defines the common methods. Then:

```
ComicStripViewCellB *comicCell = ...;
```

Or define an `@protocol` which lists the common methods, have the cell classes publicly declare that they implement the protocols (`@interface ComicStripViewCellB < ComicStripViewCell >`). Then:

```
UICollectionViewCell < ComicStripViewCellB > *comicCell = ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

If they have the same methods and properties, you could create a protocol that both of them implements. Or you could create a class that inherits from `UICollectionViewCell` with the common stuff, and make your cells inherit this class.

With protocol:

```
UICollectionViewCell<MyCellProtocol> *cell;

if (condition) {
    cell = ...
} else {
    cell = ...
}
```

With subclass:

```
MyCommonCollectionViewCell *cell;
if (condition) {
    cell = ...
} else {
    cell = ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the two custom subclasses have common properties that are not in `UICollectionViewCell`, then you should create a new superclass for them to share that does have those.  Then, the `comicStripViewCell` variable should be a pointer to that shared superclass.